# What's the difference between "administrator" and "manager"?

Tags: differences

I have a sense of saying an administrator is a person managing a website or a server, only because I hear it usually in the software field. But I am sure the word administrator was there before computers were invented.

While the term manager is called on a person "managing" a company or an organization.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

A **manager** is the sole person in charge of a group or a team of people.

An **administrator** is not necessarily in charge of a group of people; generally he is in charge of some aspect of making sure things work properly. Or in other cases he is part of a group which sits rank-wise above the managers and dictates how they should do their jobs and what should be their motives and objectives.

Sometimes the roles of the manager and the administrator converge and the administrator can be said to be acting as the manager as well, but generally they are used in different senses to indicate different responsibilities.

These might help:

- http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-manager-and-vs-administrator
- http://www.ask.com/business-finance/difference-between-administrator-manager-c4bc7ec10b17d715